# Magento 2.0.7 Web Configuration failure

Tags: installation, magento-2.0.7, installer

[image]When I am installing Magento 2.0.7 the `Next` button of the `Web Configuration` page is not working. When i click on `Next` it stay on the same page, no error message appearing on the page. What should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install another browser or clean your browser cache sometimes its stuck installation process. Experienced same thing today with chrome I used safari it worked.

Comment: I try in chrome, mozilla, Safari, Opera steel it not work

Comment: Are you trying to install with softaculous ? And they just released 2.1, I think you should try to install that using with chrome incognito mode.

Comment: install with softaculous is working well but i want manually

Comment: probably missing something in your magento files, do this way install with softaculous first, after that login ftp and delete app/etc/config.php, app/etc/env.php, delete inside of var/cache and var/generation. These will give you an option reinstall manually with working files. let me know.